# kotlin nested recyclerview add data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, kotlin

We are trying to design a nested recyclerview we get the idea that TWO adapters are used. What we are not understanding is the data source construction. We are using SQLite DB for a data source. Our design is a Parent text field that describes a Department in a grocery store. Like Produce and Liquor with child Items in these Depts being tomatoes avocados and beer.
If we use two Models and two DB Tables how do we associate the child items with the Departments?
We thought about one DB Table  with this format record 1 Produce tomatoes record 2 null avocado record 3 Liquor beer. This seems not so smart. So next we thought about JOINS or UNION call to make one new Table out of our two tables one with Dept and the other Items.
How would we lay out the two tables so they associate items with respective departments?
We are also guessing here that our ViewHolder needs to be a Class of its own that talks to the Parent and Child Adapters.
We will post a photo of the design we are trying to emulate (copy)
Our questions are how to design the DB Tables?
Do we need a ViewHolder Class that interfaces with the two Adapters?
How to create the two tables and what type of JOIN to call to make a new table?[image: Nested Layout]

We have looked at this link and the idea is great but his code does not have the same data source. One is date the other could be SQLite [Kotlin Nested](https://manticarodrigo.com/nested-android-recyclerview-kotlin/)

OK we have a working DB and the Two Adapters DeptAdapter and ItemAdapter work BUT not at the same time. The two tables DEPT_TABLE and ITEM_TABLE have data
The view for the two tables is displayed in ListActivity with a activity_list.xml
The ListActivity CAN NOT provided both table views at one time
What we think is wrong is the recyclerview declared in recyclerview_dept.xml is not involved and all the work or views are being provided by the recyclerview in the activity_list.xml with id rvListActivity

code posted below with **ONE QUESTION**

```
class ListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var RecyclerAdapter: DeptAdapter? = null
private var RecyclerAdapter2:ItemAdapter? =null
private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var recyclerView2: RecyclerView? = null
private val db = DBHelper(this)
private var deptList:List<DEPT> = ArrayList()
private var itemList:List<ITEM> = ArrayList()
private var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null
private var linearLayoutManager2: LinearLayoutManager? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list)

    initViews()

}// end onCreate

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    initDB()
}

// This is ONLY called when Activity is in onResume state
private fun initDB() {
    deptList = db.queryAllDEPT()
    //itemList = db.queryAllITEM()
    if(deptList.isEmpty()){
        title = "No Records in DB"
    }else{
        title = "Contact List"
    }
    println("########################################### onSTART")
    RecyclerAdapter = DeptAdapter(deptList = deptList, context = applicationContext)
    //RecyclerAdapter2 = ItemAdapter(itemList = itemList, context = applicationContext)
    (recyclerView as RecyclerView).adapter = RecyclerAdapter
    //(recyclerView2 as RecyclerView).adapter = RecyclerAdapter2
}

private fun initViews() {

    recyclerView = this.findViewById(R.id.rvListActivity)
    RecyclerAdapter = DeptAdapter(deptList = deptList, context = applicationContext)
    linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    (recyclerView as RecyclerView).layoutManager = linearLayoutManager!!

    //recyclerView2 = this.findViewById(R.id.rvListActivity)
    //RecyclerAdapter2 = ItemAdapter(itemList = itemList, context = applicationContext)
    //linearLayoutManager2 = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    //(recyclerView2 as RecyclerView).layoutManager = linearLayoutManager2!!
}
```

XML File for above Activity

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ListActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvListActivity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

XML file with additional recyclerview

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_new_card">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDEPT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="I am tv tvDept"
            android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvDEPT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Both Adapters

```
class DeptAdapter(deptList:List<DEPT>,internal var context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<DeptAdapter.DeptViewHolder>() {

private var deptList:List<DEPT> = ArrayList()
init{this.deptList = deptList}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DeptViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_dept,parent,false)
    return DeptViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return deptList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DeptViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val items = deptList[position]
    holder.item.text = items.dept
}

inner class DeptViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var item: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDEPT) as TextView
}
```

}

Child Adapter if you will

```
class ItemAdapter(itemList:List<ITEM>,var context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

private var itemList:List<ITEM> = ArrayList()
init{this.itemList = itemList}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item,parent,false)
    return ItemViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return itemList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val items = itemList[position]
    holder.item.text = items.gitem
}

inner class ItemViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var item: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvITEM) as TextView
}
```

}

Table Design is simple id and string both in separate Models

**Our question how to show both tables in the ListActivity?**

Comment: can you format your question?

Comment: First things first: you're asking multiple questions in one question.
Ask 1 question per question and not an overly broad question like this as it's difficult to help you out.
Your first question is about database design, so start with that. SQLite and other SQL type databases are closely related. Think about relationships between tables. For instance you have a table (`Departments`). that holds a department and an id. The different groceries then have a foreign key pointing to the id of a specific `Department`.

Comment: It's possible to answer all your questions obviously, but ask ONE question and then solve that issue. Then ask a new question to get your issue solved with the ViewHolder pattern and so on. Chances are that when you've reached the conclusion of the first question you might have solved the second question yourself.

Comment: @Darwind My apologizes for all the questions due to one part being dependent on the first part I placed all the parts on the table at one time. YES I am trying to not waste time developing the DB that will not work. So Thanks for the Foreign Key suggestion  We considered that and will test

Comment: @Grendel no problem - it's just very difficult for other people to post an answer that covers your whole situation, so it's best to take one question at the time and fix that issue and then move forward from there. The same way you'd probably write your code - one line at the time or one feature at the time or one function or method at the time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is really slick code. One issue I have not tied it to a SQLite DB yet.
When I get time to hook it up to a DB I will post an update.
You had a number of the ides correct two adapters is a must
And the List in a List is used here by adding the ChildModel to the ParentModel as a `List<ChildModel>`
This code belongs to [Navendra Jha](https://medium.com/@navendra/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047)

You will need to do a little manipulation as he thought it would be fun to have the children scroll left and right independent of the parent so in the MainActivity which displays the data change this line from horizontal to vertical

```
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
```

Navendra Jha used an ImageView in his code we commented that out once we understood what was happening under the hood. This is  **REALLY** super charged full blown great code every Kotlin developer will want in her/his tool box

Comment: You are so politically correct her/his Javendra Jha has a great article about Epoxy from Airbanb tool chest. We are not big on Library's but this one might be worth exploring. Thanks I will race you to see hooks up the DB first. I ask the folks at Grosh how they did the layout no response. Why give away your trade secrets ?